# how to capture video

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

How can i record video

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
[imagePickerController release];
```

i tried this one but i am getting image capture and i am not getting video capture.

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>


-(void)actionStartVideoRecord:(id)sender  {
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
    return;
}
UIImagePickerController* imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}






- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *mType = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if([mType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the `imagePickerController` is presented, start the videoCapture of the device.

For more info, see doc for [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

You can make a subclass of `UIImagePickerController`. There you can have a `UIButton`. On tapping that, you could start capturing the video.

Comment: i have two buttons one for capturing image and another one for recording video. I am getting camera to capture image but i am not getting the video mode to record the video